# How can i achieve this smart search in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

In my **iphone app** i have a search screen with `UISearchDisplaycontroller` uisng this against each **scopeBar** key words we can filter the search result, But using only this **scopeBar** buttons i couldnt reach my requirement.

See, I have a list of members, I need to search members based on state, country, city, name.  and i should display these search types in a bar (say **scopBar**).

After selecting a **scopeBar** button(say Country)if we type **'India'** in the search bar  it should display all the members of that country. How can i achieve these kind of search ? I have tried many search tutorials, But those didnt help me. Please help me out.

Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: It would help to know how your original data is stored and in what format it is held in your code.  For example, are you pulling the info from a SQLite database or a simple CSV file?  Is the data stored as NSDictionary or NSArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Apple's Sample code, we can use 2 arrays during search, 1 actual, and 2nd is filtered array as in example reference :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Listings/MainViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848-MainViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

But in your case, we are requiring 3 arrays, third array will be local array (let's call scopedFilteredArray)  during filteration.

1. Search all objects by scope bar : Using Predicate (contained by scopedFilteredArray, from actual array).
2. Search filtered objects from scopedFilteredArray and save them in filteredArray for display.

Comment: thanx for ur reply,,do u know any tutorial link,,

Answer (score 0):

Have a modal window appear to select your extra filter parameters (put whatever control you want there), and create a global search nsmutabledictionary to store your parameters.

I put it to appear on the book (bookmarks) button (it passed apple checks), for easy access.